# MySQL add new columns to existing table

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have a MySQL table named table1 like this

```
name
a
b
c
```

I want to add two new columns to table1.

What i want to get is

```
name list1 list2
a    1     2.5 
b    3     3.6 
c    2     3.3
```

What i tried

```
ALTER TABLE table1
ADD COLUMN list1 INT NOT null
ADD COLUMN list2 DOUBLE NOT null
```

But it errors.

How can i solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The main mistake is in your query as you forgot to add **,** after first ADD(end of 2nd line).

First copy the below script and paste it in any python file like *mysql.py*.

**Note:** You provide your own database connection parameters.

```
import MySQLdb

# CREATING DATABASE AND CURSOR OBJECT 
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "rishikesh", "rishikesh@321", "practice");
cursor = db.cursor()

# VERIFY THE MYSQL VERSION
cursor.execute("SELECT VERSION()")
mysql_version = cursor.fetchone();
print(mysql_version)

# CREATION OF TABLE, INSERTION INTO TABLE
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE table1 (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  \
    PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(5))");
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table1(name) values('a'), ('b'), ('c');");

# COMMITING CHANGES
db.commit(); 

query = """ALTER TABLE table1
        ADD COLUMN list1 INT NOT NULL,
        ADD COLUMN list2 DOUBLE NOT NULL
        """
cursor.execute(query);

# UPDATING TABLE
query = "UPDATE table1 SET list1=1, list2=2.5 WHERE id=1";
cursor.execute(query);

query = "UPDATE table1 SET list1=3, list2=3.6 WHERE id=2";
cursor.execute(query);

query = "UPDATE table1 SET list1=2, list2=3.3 WHERE id=3"
cursor.execute(query)

# COMMITING CHANGES
db.commit();

# UPDATING TABLE
query = "UPDATE table1 SET list1=1, list2=2.5 WHERE id=1";
cursor.execute(query);

query = "UPDATE table1 SET list1=3, list2=3.6 WHERE id=2";
cursor.execute(query);

query = "UPDATE table1 SET list1=2, list2=3.3 WHERE id=3"
cursor.execute(query)

# COMMITING CHANGES
db.commit();
```

Finally execute it using *python mysql.py* command. You are done.

In my case I opened the MySQL client and verified the o/p as follows.

```
mysql> USE practice;
Database changed
mysql> SHOW TABLES;  /* BEFORE RUNNING PYTHON SCRIPT */ 
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+--------------------+
| Tables_in_practice |
+--------------------+
| table1             |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM table1;  /* AFTER RUNNING PYTHON SCRIPT */
+----+------+-------+-------+
| id | name | list1 | list2 |
+----+------+-------+-------+
|  1 | a    |     1 |   2.5 |
|  2 | b    |     3 |   3.6 |
|  3 | c    |     2 |   3.3 |
+----+------+-------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is MySQL related, not Python related. Once you get your SQL syntax correct the code will work.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html 
and
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-examples.html

Hint: you are missing some commas and possibly a semi-colon(optional), and you don't need to say `COLUMN`(as it is also optional):

```
sql = """ALTER TABLE table1
         ADD list1 INT NOT null,
         ADD list2 DOUBLE NOT null;"""
```